# Java Hibernate: Download MySql or LAMP

Tags: java, mysql, lamp

I am going to be writing a Spring based Java application and I was wondering if I should install MySql directly or should I just install [LAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lampas/). I would like  to install LAMP, but would this have any side  effects with JDBC? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with the tool you linked on your question, but it does not seem what you are looking for.

[LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) stands to Linux, Apache MySQL and PHP and is a known development stack. But as you said you are going to use Spring(Java), so this does not suit you.

First you will need to install MySQL. This can be achieved by installing "MySQL Server" on Ubuntu Software Center or with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Next you will need a Java capable web server. Common choices are Tomcat or jetty

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Also you will need to check you have Java Development Kit installed. If you already have one that's ok. If not the easiest to install is OpenJDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk7-jdk
```

Finally you will need a capable IDE. Common choices are Netbeans or Eclipse. You can find both on Software Center. Also there is available in Spring website [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts), which is based on Eclipse and bundles also a webserver. So if you choose to go with it you may ignore the web server installation and use the bundled one.

Comment: Thanks, I already have Eclipse Kepler and JDK7 and the next thing I was going to do was install Tomcat. Thanks  for your  response. My application is going to be light-weight, so I should stick with Tomcat, but do you have any experience with JBoss?

Comment: If you want to use JBoss probably it is better to download it from the website than using a version from the repositories. As you are using Eclipse managing (from the developer point) it or Tomcat should be very similar.